# Validation of form with several tabs

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, tabs, webix

I have a form divided into several tabs and seems like the validation is not working on such form.

Configured as follows:

```
  elements:[
    {
      view:"tabview",
      tabbar:{ options:["Setings","Summary"]}, animate:false,
      cells:[
        { id:"Setings", rows:[
          { view:"datepicker", name:"post"}
        ]},
        { id:"Summary", rows:[
          { view:"text", name:"title", label:"New title" }
        ]}        
      ]
    }        
  ],
  rules:{
    "post":webix.rules.isNotEmpty,
    "title":webix.rules.isNotEmpty,
  }
```

As an illustration: `value` param in the `onAfterValidation` event includes only inputs from the current tab (should be filled with the invalid ones)

```
on:{
  onAfterValidation:function(result, value){
    if (!result) console.log(value);
    else console.log(value);
  }
},
```

[**Sample**](http://webix.com/snippet/74d50c34).

Any ideas how to implement validation for several tabs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. There's a possibility to invoke the validation for the hidden inputs:

```
$$("postform").validate({hidden:true});
```

[**Updated snippet**](http://webix.com/snippet/7b3f1166)